# How do I update a Listbox to display a constantly changing counter?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have a listbox which holds messages, I want to be able to count the number of each type of messages sent as and when they are.

How do I update the listbox to display a constantly changing counter?

```
def addToList(self,event):

    global transList

    ref = len(transList)
    t = TransMsg()

    t.canID = self.IDbox.get()
    t.DLC = self.DLCBox.get()
    t.canType = "s"
    t.msgType = "m"
    t.tData0 = self.tData0Box.get()
    t.tData1 = self.tData1Box.get()
    t.tData2 = self.tData2Box.get()
    t.tData3 = self.tData3Box.get()
    t.tData4 = self.tData4Box.get()
    t.tData5 = self.tData5Box.get()
    t.tData6 = self.tData6Box.get()
    t.tData7 = self.tData7Box.get()
    t.tTimer = self.tTimerBox.get()

    self.clearBoxes()

    transList.append(t)

    self.Translist.insert("end","%s %d %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %d %d" %
            ( transList[ref].canID,
             int(transList[ref].DLC),
             transList[ref].tData0,
             transList[ref].tData1,
             transList[ref].tData2,
             transList[ref].tData3,
             transList[ref].tData4,
             transList[ref].tData5,
             transList[ref].tData6,
             transList[ref].tData7,
             int(transList[ref].tTimer)
             transList[ref].Count))

def Enter(self):

        global running
        i_ref = 0
        items = self.Translist.curselection()

        if(int(transList[i_ref].tTimer) <= 0):
            pass
        else:
            if running == 0:
                self.retrans = self.window.after(transList[i_ref].tTimer, self.Enter)
            else:
                running = 0
                self.window.after_cancel(self.retrans)

        for i in items:
           i_ref = int(i)

           system('echo "%s %s 0x%s %d 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s" >/dev/pcan33' %
                (transList[i_ref].msgType,
                transList[i_ref].canType,
                transList[i_ref].canID,
                int(transList[i_ref].DLC),
                transList[i_ref].tData0,
                transList[i_ref].tData1,
                transList[i_ref].tData2,
                transList[i_ref].tData3,
                transList[i_ref].tData4,
                transList[i_ref].tData5,
                transList[i_ref].tData6,
                transList[i_ref].tData7))

           transList[i_ref].Count += 1
           #update listbox with new count
```

Here is the code for the send and insert for the listbox

Comment: Could you explain better this sentence:  `I want to be able to count the number of each type of messages sent as and when they are?` When exactly you want to change the contents of the Listbox?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530634/how-can-i-change-a-python-tk-listbox-items-text

Comment: @Rinzler Basically when a message is sent the counter increases by one, I want to be able to update the listbox with the current message and count so that the count on the listbox increases as well

Comment: But when is the message sent?

Comment: @Rinzler It's okay I've figured out the best way to do it is remove the index and re-insert it with the increased count. The only problem now is how to redraw the listbox after each event

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm